# replace the 'value' of the 'key' when 'key' is found in file

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I have a problem in replacing the value of some strings in one file into the same string found in another file.

```
test1.txt

porsche  430+turbo blue
ferrari  520+supercharged red
buggati  1001+supersport black
fiat     turbo white
```

Some strings in this test1.txt have their own values as given in test2.txt

```
test2.txt
turbo=30
supercharged=50 
supersport=100
```

I want to replace the values from test2.txt in test1.txt whenever i find the corresponding string.

```
output.txt
    porsche  460 blue
    ferrari  570 red
    buggati  1101 black
    fiat     30 white
```

Turbo from test2.txt is searched in test1.txt and then the value is replaced and summed up.

I did lot of googling and i didnt find the way to proceed with this.
Can anyone please help me out with this
thanks in advance

Comment: This is not exactly trivial … you are not only asking for a parser, but a small language interpreter.

Comment: This is actually pretty trivial. How do you think yo should proceed? Why are you writing this program? Is it homework?

Comment: I was thinking of storing the test2.txt into hash with keys and values. then search for the keys in test1.txt and replace the value in test1.txt. This is small part of my work and i am not sure how to go about this problem

Comment: That sounds exactly right; which part are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

amon's solution is nice and elegant. +1 (I don't have enough reputation points yet to leave this comment on his answer)

If you find you don't need the extensibility of an operator dispatch table, here's an alternative that's fairly straightforward:

(EDITED 2012/08/29: Incorporated amon's dispatch table for processing of +,-,*,/,^ operators)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw( -no_match_vars );

setup_for_testing( );

open my $source_file, '<',  'text1.txt' || die "Couldn't open source file: $OS_ERROR";
open my $key_file,    '<',  'text2.txt' || die "Couldn't open key file: $OS_ERROR";

# Clear the output file
open my $output_file, '>',  'output.txt' || die "Couldn't open output file: $OS_ERROR";

# Now open output file for append
open $output_file,    '>>', 'output.txt' || die "Couldn't open output file: $OS_ERROR";

# Create translation map from text2.txt
my %translation_map = translation_map( $key_file );

# Process text1.txt and print to output.txt
while ( my $source_line = <$source_file> ) {
    my $transformed_line = transform( $source_line, \%translation_map );
    print $output_file $transformed_line ||
        die "Couldn't print to output file: $OS_ERROR";;
}

# Tidy up
close $source_file || die "Couldn't close source file: $OS_ERROR";
close $key_file    || die "Couldn't close key file: $OS_ERROR";
close $output_file || die "Couldn't close output file: $OS_ERROR";

###################
sub setup_for_testing {
   open my $textfile1, '>',  'text1.txt' || die "Couldn't open source file: $OS_ERROR";
   open my $textfile2, '>',  'text2.txt' || die "Couldn't open key file: $OS_ERROR";

   my $source_text =<<'END_TEXT';
porsche  430-turbo blue
ferrari  520*supercharged red
buggati  1001+supersport black
fiat     turbo white
END_TEXT

   my $key_file_text =<<'END_TEXT';
turbo=30
supercharged=50
supersport=100
END_TEXT

   print $textfile1 $source_text   || die "Couldn't print to text1.txt: $OS_ERROR";
   print $textfile2 $key_file_text || die "Couldn't print to text2.txt: $OS_ERROR";

   close $textfile1 || die "Couldn't close source file: $OS_ERROR";
   close $textfile2 || die "Couldn't close key file: $OS_ERROR";

   return; # intentional void return
}

sub translation_map {
    my $key_file = shift;

    my %translation_map;
    while ( my $key_mapping = <$key_file> ) {
        chomp $key_mapping;

        # The regex /x option allows whitespace in the regular expression for readability
        my ( $key, $value ) = split / \s* = \s* /x, $key_mapping;
        $translation_map{ $key } = $value;
    }

    return %translation_map;
}

sub transform {
    my $source_line = shift @_;
    my %value_for   = %{ shift @_ };

    my $transformed_line = $source_line;

    foreach my $key ( keys %value_for ) {
        # The regex /e option causes the rights side of a substitution to be evaluated as
        # a Perl expression.
        my $value = $value_for{ $key };
        my ( $before_expression, $lvalue, $operator, $rvalue_key, $after_expression ) =
            ( $transformed_line =~ m/ \A
                                      ( .*? )
                                      ( \d+ ) ([-+*\/^]?) ( $key )
                                      ( .* )
                                      \Z
                                    /x );

        if ( $operator  ) {
            my $rvalue = $value_for{ $rvalue_key };

            # Using the dispatch table from amon's answer
            my $value_of_expression = {
              '+' => sub {$_[0] +  $_[1]},
              '-' => sub {$_[0] -  $_[1]},
              '*' => sub {$_[0] *  $_[1]},
              '/' => sub {$_[0] /  $_[1]},
              '^' => sub {$_[0] ** $_[1]},
            }->{$operator}->($lvalue, $rvalue);

            $transformed_line =
                $before_expression . $value_of_expression . $after_expression . "\n";
        } else {
            $transformed_line =~ s/$key/$value/;
        }
    }

    return $transformed_line;
}
```

This script creates the test files text1.txt and text2.txt according to your question specifications and then does the transformation and outputs to output.txt:

```
> ls
stackoverflow-12169648_replace_value_of_key.pl

> perl stackoverflow-12169648_replace_value_of_key.pl 

> ls
output.txt                  text1.txt
stackoverflow-12169648_replace_value_of_key.pl  text2.txt

> more text1.txt 
porsche  430+turbo blue
ferrari  520+supercharged red
buggati  1001+supersport black
fiat     turbo white

> more text2.txt 
turbo=30
supercharged=50
supersport=100

> more output.txt 
porsche  460 blue
ferrari  570 red
buggati  1101 black
fiat     30 white
```

Hope this is useful.

.david

Comment: Why is it necessary to give my input files in the code???? Cant I just access it thruogh some file name or filehandle???

Comment: Sorry for confusing you.  I didn't mean to suggest that your final solution should have those example files hardcoded in the code.  I just put it there to make it more convenient for you to verify whether or not the script does what you need it to do.  After that, no need for the setup_for_testing() function anymore.  I do a lot of test-driven development so I guess I'm used to writing tests. :)  Glad it was helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, it wasnt confusing but i just felt it unnecesary. Thank you again..

Comment: David what if i have subtraction and multiplication operator("-" or "*") in place of "+" ??? how can i modify this code to work for any of these operators

Comment: This is overkill by a very long way. There is no reason at all, for instance, to open the output file twice, and most of your code is there to generate the test files. The profusion of comments and subroutines only hide the functionality of your program

Comment: Also you shouldn't `use English` in general. Everybody knows what `$!` is, but I had to look up `$OS_ERROR`. It is no more descriptive and just adds to the noise in your program

Comment: @unkaitha: I edited the code to accommodate other arithmetic operators and tested it with "-" and "*".  Take a lot at the changes in the transform() function: I used the dispatch table from amon's answer.

Comment: @Borodin: I appreciate your point of view about `use English`, but you should realize that there are a great many Perl programmers who think the exact opposite.  Perl has been heavily criticized in the programming world for being crytic and difficult to read, and hence not practical for collaborative projects.  I personally have co-workers who are competent programmers who don't want to have anything to do with Perl for just this reason.  I got the feeling that unkaitha is a new Perl programmer so I wanted to set a good example by using best practices.

Comment: @Borodin cont'd:   Perhaps you and many other veteran Perl programmers recognize $! on sight, but I think for a new programmer or someone coming from another language that $OS_ERROR is a lot more descriptive.  Also, turning off -no_match_vars speeds up regex processing.

Comment: @Borodin: regarding opening output.txt twice - it was so unkaitha could run this script many times, making changes to the input data.  The output.txt has to be cleared or the repeated script runs will keep appending.  I didn't build the string in one go and write it to file all at once because if the output is extremely large this doesn't scale.  Not knowing the true size of unkaitha's inputs I chose the safer method.  All of this was done for convenience to make testing and verification easier.  It's how I write code for co-workers too.  Thanks for your input, though.  Best regards.

Comment: @David: IMO the main reason Perl has gained such prejudice because of its comprehensive built-in regex support. Regular expressions are symbolic and impregnable, but even now that most languages support them - usually via some library device - the prejudices lives on, and the people who live their lives by them are bigots. I suggest you avoid associating with them rather than trying to please them. `OS_ERROR` isn't useful as it still could really mean anything.

The second open is unnecesary because an open for write followed by an open for append is the same as a simple open for write.

Comment: @David: I'm afraid that, if that is your normal programming style, you are doing a lot to fuel the anti-Perl feelings. As I said originally, putting chunks of code into subroutines that are called only once means I have to scan all over the program to find what the call does. And your code should be written clearly so that comments are unnecessary: so much ink on the paper leaves people searching for the code amongst the comments. The key to lucidity is to write idiomatically, so that your code looks like all the best programs out there

Comment: @David: can u help me over in this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242557/input-to-the-program-with-all-the-strings-in-an-array-one-by-one

Comment: @Borodin: Keep in mind that the script I wrote above was to help out unkaitha, who is almost certainly a beginner.  You are correct that the comments I wrote would have been unnecessary for normal production code, I only wrote them for unkaitha's benefit.  I included the test harness code for the same reason, to make things more convenient for verification.  I agree I probably went overboard in my attempt to make it educational.

Comment: @Borodin:   We'll have to agree to disagree on the OS_ERROR type stuff.  If you google around for Perl best practices you'll find that there are many who suggest this.  As for the use of subroutines for chunking code, this is standard practice for programmers who do test-driven development.  You can't unit test if the code is not grouped into units.  That they are only called once here is a function of the example being used.

Comment: @Borodin: Had to open the file to write in order to truncate it.  If I opened it for append each time the script is run the output file grows.  Becomes hard to verify.

Comment: @unkaitha: I only just now had a chance to take a look at your other question.  Looks like you got what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the first file (called *A*) has three columns seperated by one or more whitespace characters. The second column may include an aritmetic expression with decimal numbers and variables seperated by basic (infix) operators. The variable values are fixed in another file, henceforth called *B*.

Preparing the variables is trivial:

```
my %variables = map {chomp; split /=/, $_, 2} do {
  open my $file, "<", $filename_B or die;
  <$file>;
};
```

Parsing the other file is more difficult. Assuming it is opened into the filehandle `$fileA` we loop over the lines and split each line into three fields:

```
while (defined(my $line = <$fileA>)) {
   chomp $line;
   my ($model, $expression, $color) = split /\s+/, $line, 3;
   my $value = parseExpression($expression);
   print "\t$model $value $color\n"; # use printf to prettyprint if needed
}
```

We then print out the expressions value along with the other data, assuming you want to print to STDOUT.

Our sub `parseExpression` will split the expression string at operators. Variable names will be substituted. Then the operations are performed strictly right-associatively. While this makes parsing easier this doesn't exactly come natural: `3*4+1` evaluates to `15`. We use recursion because I prefer it over iteration to be able to solve multiple operations:

```
sub parseExpression {
  my ($string) = @_;
  my ($part, $operator, $rest) = ($string =~ /(\w+)([-+*\/^]?)(.*$)/g);
  if (not $operator) {
    # $part is the whole expression
    my $value = exists $variables{$part} ? $variables{$part} : $part;
    die if $value =~ /[a-z]/i; # The variable name was not substituted
    return $value;
  } else {
    my $rval = parseExpression($rest);
    my $lval = parseExpression($part); # you don't need this
                                       # if there are no variables on the left
    my $value = {
      '+' => sub {$_[0] +  $_[1]},
      '-' => sub {$_[0] -  $_[1]},
      '*' => sub {$_[0] *  $_[1]},
      '/' => sub {$_[0] /  $_[1]},
      '^' => sub {$_[0] ** $_[1]},
    }->{$operator}->($lval, $rval);
    return $value;
  }
}
```

We use a cute little dispatch table to perform the appropriate calculation for each operator. You can always enhance the operator regex and the table to support additional operators.

Beware that the current implementation allows numbers as variable names. Not something you might want, but it makes life easier.

There may be some interesting problems with undefined values springing up randomly, but this code should give you a pointer towards the right direction. (You can remove the recursion if you only allow one operation in the second column)

Answer (score 1):

This is simply done by performing the replacement in two steps. First find all keywords that exist in the `%values` hash derived from the `test2.txt` file. Then look for multiple decimal numbers connected by an arithemtic operator and evaluate the expression to form the replacement.

The regex to find the hash keys is built dynamically using `join` to connect the using the regex alternation operator `|`.

The second regex amounts to

```
expression ::= digits, operator, digits, { operator, digits }
```

and allows whitespace between the terms

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %values = do {
  open my $fh, '<', 'test2.txt' or die $!;
  local $/;
  <$fh> =~ /\w+/g;
};

my $regex = join '|', keys %values;

open my $fh, '<', 'test1.txt' or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
  s/\b($regex)\b/$values{$1}/g;
  s|([0-9]+(\s*[-+*/]\s*[0-9]+)+)|$1|eeg;
  print;
}
```

**output**

```
porsche  460 blue
ferrari  570 red
buggati  1101 black
fiat     30 white
```

Comment: It's clear we come from very different coding style philosophies. :) I tend to favor readability over conciseness.  I really like how you solved it, though.  It works for multiple expressions per line, whereas mine assumed only one expression per line. +1

Comment: I'm no perl expert, but David's version was a lot easier to understand.

Comment: @Borodin This works fine for me when i have multiple expressions but i dont no why i have undesirable results when their is only one expression per line... Thank you for such a compact code.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't code in perl at all, but I thought I might just offer some overall tips...

First in order for this to be kept simple, you would have to somewhat commit to a limited pattern format, otherwise as suggested in a comment, this will become a language parser. So you might have to say a line in test1.txt may or may not contain `[numbers][operator][characters]` pattern.

So what I might suggest is parsing test2.txt into an associative array (hash), so that you have something like:

```
{
    "turbo"        =>  30,
    "supercharged" =>  50,
    "supersport"   => 100,
}
```

Then for each line in test1.txt, you can perform a regex match on a pattern like:
`\b((\d+)([+])(\w+))\b`

From this pattern you can check for a `+` operator, and for the key. If you get them, you can lookup the key in your hash, and perform an eval on the `parsed number, operator, hash[key] => value`

If you only want to handle a `+`, then you can simply convert the numbers to `int` and add them. Otherwise to support multiple operator patterns, you would have to either handle them explicitly or **safely** eval the string.

You can regex substitute on that first primary capture group